# mysql dateformat with jquery date format not working out

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui, datetime

I have a `mypage.php` and it contains the below code

And i have added the

```
<link style="text/css" href="http://jqueryui.com/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>

<form name="test_date" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="datepicker1" name="date1">
    <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Insert and show">
</form>
```

And In `jquery.ui.datepicker.js` i have change the date format to `dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'` from `dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'`

and below is the jquery for selecting the date when click on textbox

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

And when i click on submit button i have inserted into mysql database database

```
<?php
if($_POST['insert']) {
echo "Date : ";
$d = $_POST['date1'];

require('con_open.php');

$t = date('Y-m-j H:i:s', strtotime($d));
mysql_query("insert into date_table (date_field1) values ('$t')");

echo "Converted to Date at Runtime :" . $t;
echo "<br>";
$query = mysql_query("select date_field1 from date_table");
while($r = mysql_fetch_row($query))
{
    got_date_db = $r[0];
}
echo "Displaying date from Database : " . got_date_db;

require('con_close.php');
}
?>
```

Output :

`Converted to Date at Runtime : 2011-12-28 14:32:16`

`Displaying date from Database : 0000-00-00 00:00:00`

`date_field1 (DATETIME) fromat on mysql`

Even i have tried out checking with dateformat of mysql and php date function manuals online and over stackoverflow... but i could not get any solution to this one.

Comment: try inserting some default date like, setting, $t = '2011-12-12 10:10:16'; then perform insert query and see if it gets inserted well..!

Comment: yes! its working out with manually like you said, but not

Comment: You should share your date_table table definitions.

Comment: already shared here it is `date_field1 (DATETIME)` format on mysql

Comment: Okay, after your `mysql_query("insert..` statement; add this: `echo mysql_error();`

Comment: not displaying any kind of error

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mysql_query("
  insert into date_table (date_field1)
  values (FROM_UNIXTIME(". (int)strtotime($_POST['date1']) ."))
");
```

I think its generally a good idea to pass a date as a timestamp to the database. Then you don't have to worry about formatting it the right way.